# 6 different time series using np.random.norm

Tags: python

I want to use the np.random.norm function for 6 different means and standard deviations. I did this to get the means and standard deviations:

```
stdev_rebuilt_ts = []

mean_rebuilt_ts = []

#noise_rebuilt_time_series = []

for basin in range(6):
    stdev_rebuilt_ts.append(np.std(merge_months_detrended_1992_2016[basin,:]))
    mean_rebuilt_ts.append(np.mean(merge_months_detrended_1992_2016[basin,:]))
    
stdev_rebuilt_ts = np.array(stdev_rebuilt_ts)
mean_rebuilt_ts = np.array(mean_rebuilt_ts)
```

Which works and and gives:

```
print(mean_rebuilt_ts)
print(stdev_rebuilt_ts)

[4.1007996e-07 3.0199686e-07 1.5735627e-07 8.7420142e-09 1.3732911e-06
 1.6403199e-06]
[7.070564   4.4405646  1.2779348  0.16246584 5.2273583  3.023601  ]
```

Using the mean and standard deviations, for the first mean and first standard deviation, I want one time series, like np.random.norm(mean_rebuilt_ts[0],stdev_rebuilt_ts[0],time_months[-300:].size), and then another time series for mean_rebuilt_ts[1], [2], etc.

I tried a nested for loop:

```
mean = []
stdev = []

noise_rebuilt_time_series = []

for basin in range(6):
    mean.append(np.mean(merge_months_detrended_1992_2016[basin,:]))
    stdev.append(np.std(merge_months_detrended_1992_2016[basin,:]))
    for i in mean:
        for j in stdev:
            noise_rebuilt_time_series.append(np.random.normal(i,j,time_months[-300:].size))
    
noise_rebuilt_time_series = np.array(noise_rebuilt_time_series)
```

But it makes only one time series of the size 91, 300, rather than of the shape 6,300.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears as though you are just overwriting the `noise_rebuilt_time_series` each time.  For each mean you are iterating over all the stdevs which sounds like that is unintended.

```
noise_rebuilt_time_series = np.zeros((6,300))
for c,(i, j) in enumerate(zip(a,b)):
    noise_rebuilt_time_series[c] = np.random.normal(i,j,time_months[-300:].size)
```

Comment: what does c repersent in this case? i and j being the mean and standard deviation

Comment: c = count IOW which iteration is the loop on.